# How to open a directory/folder on a machine on LAN using python?

Tags: python, sockets

I am designing a website for a local server on our lan, so that anyone who tires to access that IP from a browser sees a web page and when he clicks on some link on that web page then a directory or some folder from that server should open.
I am using python for this purpose and the server is just like another PC with windows installed.

Comment: Your question description is not clear, do you want to implement a web server that will display the contents of a directory ?

Comment: Sort of, but through some interface like a web page. I also want to scan the files being uploaded and before downloading.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to redirect the user to your file server, then it sort of depends on what operating system they're using.  If everybody's going to be on Windows, then you should be able to include a link to "//Your-Fileserver-Name/Path1/Path2".  Obviously you have to share the appropriate files on your server using Windows file-sharing.